# Using residuals as noise and EWMA to fill in missing values?

Tags: time-series, residuals, missing-data, data-imputation, moving-average

For some time series data on booking transactions, I am attempting to use EWMA (exponential weighted moving average) + randomized residuals to fill in the missing data. That is, after calculating the EWMA from the datapoints, I calculate the residuals, then resample the residuals and then add them to the ewma to fill in the null totalBookings. TotalBookings are expressed in $ and their distribution is lognormal.

This [approach](https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkStats2/blob/master/code/chap12ex.ipynb) follows the same one used in Chapter 12 of Allen Downey's book, "thinkstats"

I follow his approach for my own dataset:

```py
def FillMissing(daily, span=30):
    """Fill missing values with exponentially weighted moving average"""
    daily = daily.set_index('bookedDate')
    dates = pd.date_range(daily.index.min(), daily.index.max())
    reindexed = daily.reindex(dates)

    ewma = reindexed.totalBookings.ewm(span=span).mean()
    resid = (reindexed.totalBookings - ewma).dropna() 

    fake_data = ewma + np.random.choice(resid, len(reindexed), replace=True)
    reindexed.totalBookings.fillna(fake_data, inplace=True)

    reindexed['ewma'] = ewma
    reindexed['resid'] = reindexed.totalBookings - ewma

    return reindexed
```

The problem I'm encountering is that `fake_data` can take on negative values because some of the residuals are so large. How should I handle these cases and proceed?

Comment: This problem is evidence your model is inappropriate for your data.  But to even begin the conversation, we need to know more about your data: would they be monetary amounts? Counts?  A ratio?  Something else?

Comment: @whuber: I don't think this means that the model is inappropriate, and I think there is a straightforward answer that should work in general: work on a log scale. With some caveats, of course, e.g., that if there are "many" missing values, a simple resampling may mess up any structure the data has. I'll nominate for reopening.

Comment: @Stephen Working on a log scale is a different model!

Comment: The data is monetary amounts and the distribution I found was lognormal